# Ambigous column name, cannot get table by group_id

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have SQL code to call my table in my Laravel controller like this:

```
elseif(auth()->user()->group_id){
                $media = MediaOrder::memberOf(auth()->user()->group_id)
                ->join('users','users.nik','=','media_order.created_by')
                ->select('media_order.*','users.nickname')
                ->get();
```

But when I tried it it come up with an ambiguous column error, like this:

> LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'group_id'. (SQL: select
> [media_order].*, [users].[nickname] from [media_order] inner join
> [users] on [users].[nik] = [media_order].[created_by] where [group_id]
> = 6) {"userId":"101","exception":{"errorInfo":["42000",209,"[Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name
> 'group_id'."]}

Does anyone has an solution to this? For joining between tables is working, but I just don't know how to use where to get the table based on `group_id`.

Thank you!.

Comment: both tables have a column named group_id or only one table? please add related table structures

Comment: both table have group_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like both the `media_order` and `users` tables have a `group_id` column, so perhaps something like the following will allow you to distiguish between them...

```php
$media = DB::table('media_order')
  ->join('users','users.nik','=','media_order.created_by')
  ->select('media_order.*','users.nickname')
  ->where('media_order.group_id', '=', auth()->user()->group_id)
  ->get();
```

Comment: i just change it into something like this :
`$media=MediaOrder::join('users','users.nik','=','media_order.created_by')->select('media_order.*','users.nickname')->where('media_order.group_id','=', auth()->user()->group_id)->get();`
and it working now, thank you!